# change the text of the first span with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried a number of things but I cannot get my code to work. I want to change the text of the span containing a number in this code:

```
<li class="top">
  <div class="sec">
            <span>123</span>
            <span class="inner">Lorem</span>
    </div>
</li>
```

My JavaScript/JQuery:

```
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('li.top .sec').find('span').eq(0).text('cccc');
  });
})(jQuery);
```

I've been able to write code that changes both spans, but not the one.

Comment: Use `jQuery(function($){ ... })` for a mixin of the first two lines...

Comment: Your code appears to work fine (the 123 changes to 'cccc').  What do you mean by " I can only get two spans to change but not the first span"?

Comment: @Jonasw This is solving the problem, thank you so much, however I don't get that! Can I read this somewhere in the internet? Which key words should I use here? Thanks agaiin!!

Comment: @mola221 this should not have changed anything ( despite the much more readable code...) , so probably the error was somewhere else...

Comment: Here 123 also changed to ccc when you use the code  `$('li.top .sec').find('span').eq(0).text('cccc');` if you use  this code `$('li.top .sec').find('span').eq(1).text('cccc');` the second span will be changed.

Comment: Just tried this in JSFiddle with your exact code; worked perfectly. There are a few more alternatives to what you have though. `.find("span:eq(0)")` or `.find("span:first");` or `.find("p").first();`. You could even find the span in the first selector: `$('li.top .sec span:first');`

Answer (score 1):

Your code body appears to work to largely work.

I just tried inserting this line into the doc as follows:

```
 $('li.top .sec').find('span').eq(0).text('cccc');
```

See http://jsbin.com/leyasiwexu/edit?html,js,output

So, perhaps there is something else that is causing the issue?

```js
console.log($('li.top .sec').find('span').eq(0).text());
     $('li.top .sec').find('span').eq(0).text('cccc')
console.log('changed to: ' + $('li.top .sec').find('span').eq(0).text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="top">
  <div class="sec">
            <span>123</span>
            <span class="inner">Lorem</span>
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('li.top .sec').find('.inner').prev().text('cccc');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="top">
    <div class="sec">
        <span>123</span>
        <span class="inner">Lorem</span>
    </div>
</li>
```

> the `.prev()` method searches for the predecessor of each of these elements in the DOM tree and constructs a new jQuery object from the matching elements.
>
> The method optionally accepts a selector expression of the same type that can be passed to the $() function. If the selector is supplied, the preceding element will be filtered by testing whether it match the selector.

Excerpt taken from the [JQuery `prev` documentation](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)

Comment: can someone explain me why downote?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you havent done anything to explain what the issue was and how to fix it. All you have is a block of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$('li.top .sec').find('.inner').prev().text('cccc');
```

Answer (score -1):

I haven't checked, [HTML Specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/), but I don't think its appropriate to nest a `div` inside  `li`. I know you can work your way around presentation irregularities with css, but this might not be permissible with jQuery. Just as I said, I haven't verified. If you have to nest items inside `li`, use **inline** elements. `div` is **block**

Comment: You could have gone ahead and read the spec you linked to instead of guessing.  https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element  `li` can contain "flow content", which includes the `div`.